# Anaconda does not find any module after Ubuntu upgrade to 18.04

Tags: python, module, anaconda

After upgrading my Ubuntu OS from 16.04 LTS to 18.04.4 LTS, my python anaconda distribution does not find any regular module that should be in anaconda (numpy, matplotlib...), for instance, starting python from the command shell:

```
pjacquot@HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3:python
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:51:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>>>
```

I can not even start spyder:

```
pjacquot@HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3:~$ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pjacquot/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 7, in <module>
    from spyder.app.start import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder'
```

I checked that I was using the "good" python:

```
pjacquot@HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3:which python
/home/pjacquot/anaconda3/bin/python
```

and that the directory is in my path:

```
pjacquot@HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3: echo $PATH
/home/pjacquot/anaconda3/bin:/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux
```

Any idea what's happened there ?

I can still re install all modules, but it's going around the bush as they should be somewhere around here...

Comment: Can you show how you're starting the interpreter? I'm guessing the issue is the same if you run a script instead? Have you tried creating a new environment?

Comment: I m calling python from a command shell
```
pjacquot@inria-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3:~$ python
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:51:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Have you tried with a Conda environment?

Answer (score 0):

The not-clever solution: delete old anaconda (sudo rm -rf anaconda3) and reinstall it from scratch (takes 3 minutes and works...).